# Flutter Foreground Notifications with condition

Tags: flutter

I implemented a simple chat functionality using flutter null_safety and firebase_messaging.

I created a notification.dart service where i check the messages. this service is called in the main dart.

when the app is in foreground notifications are not shown, so i thinked about using overlay_support which looks pretty easy to use.

my question now is, is there a possibility to check my actual screen.. for example i want to show that a new chat message is incoming.. but not when i am on the actual screen, where the user is actually writing.. but everywhere else in the app

```
      _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();

      RemoteMessage message = await _firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage();
      if (message != null) {
        handleIncomingNavigation(message);
      }

      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((RemoteMessage message) async {
        handleIncomingNavigation(message);
      });

*************
      //Listen for incoming notifications in foreground
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
        //how to check here the current route?
        if(actualpath != ??) {
          showSimpleNotification(
            Text("New chat message from $user"),
            background: Colors.white
          );
        } else {
          //Do nothing
      });
**************

      //Listen for incoming notifications from background
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        handleIncomingNavigation(message);
      });
```

Update:
in my main.dart i set the Navigatorkey:

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: HomePage(),
      navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,
    )
```

i dont have a context in my service so i tried with Navigatorkey:

```
      //Listen for incoming notifications in foreground
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        var route = 
   ModalRoute.of(NavigationService.instance.navigationKey.currentContext).settings.name;
        print(route);
      });
```

but this is always crashing..

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could probably just call `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(...)` in the relevant screen (For example, the chat screen)

Comment: no i want it on all other screens than on the chat screen :-) so i made a service which is called in the beginning of main.dart.. i just need an exception for specially this one screen

Comment: Please edit your code to include a sample of your navigation scheme. There is not enough information to determine how exactly the screens relate in the code. Otherwise you might be able to use `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name` to get the current route name, if you're using the Navigator

Comment: @MikiMints thanks for you answer, i added some code.. is this what you mean? :)

Comment: Great, thanks! Though when you state that your code is crashing, it's best to also include the stack trace. Or otherwise a minimal reproducible code snippet.